# date on email received (jan 19th 2038)

Tags: controller

I have a controller (on cakephp) to send an email. But the user receive the email with a wrong date and always the same: 19th january 2038 4:14 (it seem to be the 2038 bug).
I have done some tests but I don't manage to find the right parameters to include on controller page. Here is the code:

function _sendNewMessageNotification($message_id){
            $q = $this->Message->findById($message_id) ;

```
        $this->Email->to = $q['Receiver']['email'] ;
        //$this->Email->bcc = array('secret@xxxx.fr');
        $this->Email->subject = 'You have a new message on Xxxxxx';
        $this->Email->replyTo = 'contact@xxxx.fr';
        $this->Email->from = 'Xxxxx <contact@xxxx.fr>';
        $this->Email->template = 'messages/new_message_notification'; // note no '.ctp'
              //Send as 'html', 'text' or 'both' (default is 'text')
        $this->Email->sendAs = 'html'; // because we like to send pretty mail
              //Set view variables as normal
              //Do not pass any args to send()
        $this->set('message', $q) ;               
        $this->Email->send();
```

Many thanks in advance if you can help

Answer (score -1):

I added:

`$this->Email->date = 'members/date';`

It's working well